# issues with c++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map

I am preparing for coding interviews so I have been writing some c++ code on a website that has a nice grab bag of sample problems. When trying to compile my code on the website (not really sure what compiler version the website runs under the hood) I get a very peculiar unordered_map error. I have never run into this issue before, I did some research and find out the error was occurring due to how I was initializing my unordered_map. When initializing my unordered_map I use a c++ string as my key and value, for some reason the compiler is not liking that. The compiler keeps saying there is no hash function for "basic_string" but I am not using a basic_string, I am using a c++ string

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void typeahead(const vector<string> &usernames, const vector<string> &queries) {

//error occurs right here at this initialization 
//of HistoryHash
unordered_map<string, string> HistoryHash;
unordered_map<string, string>::iterator it;
string cur_query, cur_usrnm;
locale loc;
//------------------------------------
//rest of code irrelevant
```

Here is the complete/full error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:45:0,
                 from user_file.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_string<char>; _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Value = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >; _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _Equal = std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> >; _H1 = std::hash<std::basic_string<char> >; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; bool
__cache_hash_code = true; bool __constant_iterators = false; bool __unique_keys = true]':
user_file.cpp:56:52:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:1410:61: error: no matching function for call to '__distance_fw(std::basic_string<char>&, std::basic_string<char>&)'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:1410:61: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:45,
                 from user_file.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:44:5: note: template<class _Iterator> typename std::iterator_traits::difference_type std::__detail::__distance_fw(_Iterator, _Iterator, std::input_iterator_tag)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:44:5: note:
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:45:0,
                 from user_file.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:1410:61: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:45,
                 from user_file.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:50:5: note: template<class _Iterator> typename std::iterator_traits::difference_type std::__detail::__distance_fw(_Iterator, _Iterator, std::forward_iterator_tag)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:50:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:45:0,
from user_file.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:1410:61: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:45,
                 from user_file.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:56:5: note: template<class _Iterator> typename std::iterator_traits::difference_type std::__detail::__distance_fw(_Iterator, _Iterator)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:56:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In substitution of 'template<class _Iterator> typename std::iterator_traits::difference_type std::__detail::__distance_fw(_Iterator, _Iterator) [with _Iterator = std::basic_string<char>]':
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:1410:61:   required from 'void std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_string<char>; _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Value = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >; _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _Equal = std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> >; _H1 = std::hash<std::basic_string<char> >; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; bool __cache_hash_code = true; bool __constant_iterators = false; bool __unique_keys = true]'
user_file.cpp:56:52:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:56:5: error: no type named 'difference_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<std::basic_string<char> >'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/unordered_map:45:0,
                 from user_file.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::basic_string<char>; _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Value = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >; _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _Equal = std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> >; _H1 = std::hash<std::basic_string<char> >; _H2 = std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing; _Hash = std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash; _RehashPolicy = std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy; bool __cache_hash_code = true; bool __constant_iterators = false; bool __unique_keys = true]':
user_file.cpp:56:52:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:1418:2: error: no match for 'operator++' in '++__first'
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/hashtable.h:1419:4: error: no match for 'operator*' in '*__first'"
```

Comment: That snippet of error is almost useless. It's all for one instantiation info. Please show the whole error, or at least the actual error message.

Comment: You should try to reduce this to a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem. Most of your code seems irrelevant.

Comment: I said the error occurs at the unordered_map initialization but I can edit it and reduce it

Comment: `std::string` and `std::wstring` are `typedef`ed from `std::basic_string`.

Comment: I just made an edit so it should be clearer now.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I understand but what can I do to fix this, I have used <string> as my key and value pairs in unordered_map before and never ran into this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks wrong:

```
 HistoryHash.insert(cur_query, local_min);
```

There is no overload of [`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) which takes two strings. Presumably you want

```
HistoryHash.insert(std::make_pair(cur_query, local_min));
```

Comment: yes I noticed that but that line is not the cause of my main error. The large nasty error is happening at where I initialize the unordered_map

Comment: @AyBayBay Have you tried removing that line? It compiles for me, so maybe your standard library isn't fully compliant.

Comment: this seemed to do the trick, thanks for the help. I cant believe that line could create such nasty errors c++ really sucks!